# Software architecture design: which design should I use?

Tags: api, architecture, server, client-server

I have designed a Client/Server architecture. In this system, a client can call some services -which are implemented on server- by an API call. Since the client must send some specific options, I am doubtful on some parts of this architecture design. These options are listed below:

```
{
 "query" : "sample",
 "search_engine" : "google" //can be anything else such as bing or etc.
}
```

As you know, I can use 2 patterns in this architecture including:

1. The client can embed `search_engine` option in a json and post it
   tho the server. In this case, server has to parse input json (maybe by a `switch case`) and
   produce results according to its options.
2. The server offers some kinds of services for each type of `search_engine` options. So the client simply calls these services by a `GET` request.

I am not sure whether the first choice is going to be a good design or the second. Since I already have heard that in client/server architectures, the performance is an important factor, which design do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way URLs are built, you can have `search_engine` passed as a parameter of the query string like

```
/api/controller/google
/api/controller/bing
```

and have `query` passed in JSON payload.
This gives you the freedom to process the `search_engine` parameter whether by having a primitive switch or something more sophisticated like separate services.

In order to get a better picture, try estimating the *effort* required to add another `search_engine` after the system is built.
Also, if you test your software, which approach would be easier (yet effective) to write tests for.